# How to reduce padding between each table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to reduce the padding surrounding each table view cell in a table view? I understand I could do this through a custom solution but I would like to have the default auto-resizing behavior of a standard table view cells but just reduce the padding between cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but when working with table view cells, I generally

1. Get rid of the line operator
2. Set the background color of the cell and the table view to be the same
3. Create a subview that is essential all the design of the cell

By doing this I can make the subview a different color and increase or decrease its size, and in a way, it acts as padding between cells.

Again I'm not totally sure if that helped, but if it and you would like the code for that just respond to my answer.